# How does one split a list in python at all points that meet a condition?

Tags: python

How does one split a list in python at all points that meet a condition? I spent time going through the many list splitting questions here, and couldn't find one that addresses this issue.

For example, given a list `[1,2,4,5,2,3,5]` and a condition `odd number`, I realize one can do something like this:

```
l = [1,2,4,5,2,3,5]
split = []
for item in l:
    if item%2==1:
        split.append([])
    split[-1].append(item)
```

and then

```
split == [[1, 2, 4], [5, 2], [3], [5]]
```

Is there a faster (assuming n `append`s is slow for large data sets) and/or a simple one liner or builtin function such as `<module>.split(l, key=lambda item:item%2==1)`?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629252/pythonic-way-to-split-a-list-after-elements-for-which-a-given-predicate-is-true) is a similar question. IMO your approach is readable and works fine.

Comment: @SukritKalra True. Didn't think to search for the word predicate :). Deleting question.